# How do I return an Entity Framework Entity from a WCF Data Service Webget?

Tags: entity-framework, entity, wcf-data-services

I'm trying to return a simple object (that was created in an EDMX with EF 4) through a WebGet operation in my WCF Data Service. I'm able to see the object, but the property that is an object is not populated (int this Case DisplaySize is empty, even though I've set it. I'm planning on making a database call to populate this from a non-EF generated table because we haven't migrated all the data to the new schema yet. (please infer the object types from this)

```
[WebGet]
    [SingleResultAttribute]
    public Display GetDisplay(int displayId)
    {
        Display foundDisplay = new Display();           
        foundDisplay.DisplaySize = new DisplaySize() { Id = 1, Width = 1024, Height = 768, Dimensions = "1024 X 768" };
        foundDisplay.Id = displayId;
        return foundDisplay;
    }
```

the url call I'm using: http://localhost:1354/services/EDMDataService.svc/GetDisplay?displayId=1
The xml from the call is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xml:base="http://localhost:1354/services/EDMDataService.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>http://localhost:1354/services/EDMDataService.svc/Displays(1)</id>
  <title type="text"></title>
  <updated>2010-11-12T19:34:29Z</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <link rel="edit" title="Display" href="Displays(1)" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/DisplaySize" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="DisplaySize" href="Displays(1)/DisplaySize" />
  <link rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Address" type="application/atom+xml;type=entry" title="Address" href="Displays(1)/Address" />
  <category term="DataModels.Display" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
  <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:DisplaySizeID m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:DisplaySizeID>
      <d:DisplayTypeID m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:DisplayTypeID>
      <d:TimeZoneID m:type="Edm.Int32" m:null="true" />
      <d:Facing m:null="true" />
      <d:PanelNumber m:type="Edm.Int32" m:null="true" />
      <d:DisplayTemplateTypeID m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:DisplayTemplateTypeID>
      <d:DisplayGUID m:null="true" />
      <d:RegistrationKey m:null="true" />
      <d:FirmwareVersion m:null="true" />
      <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Id>
      <d:Base m:type="DataModels.Base">
        <d:Title>test</d:Title>
        <d:Summary>Description would go here</d:Summary>
        <d:DataCenterSiteID m:type="Edm.Int32">0</d:DataCenterSiteID>
      </d:Base>
    </m:properties>
  </content>
</entry>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add &$expand=DisplaySize to your URL, and the response will contain the expanded entity as well.